# Non-constant IID distribution with identical order statistics.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, order-statistics

Is there a **non-constant** distribution $\mathbb{D}$ such that if $X_1, ..., X_n \sim \mathbb{D}$ are iid random variables with order statistics $Y_{(1)}, ..., Y_{(n)}$, then the distribution of $Y_{(i)} | Y_{(1)}, ..., Y_{(i-1)}$ is identical?

The constant distribution (say $X_i=1$ w.p $1$) satisfies this. My intuition says no, but then again I'm not sure if it might be true for something like the exponential distribution (or similar families) because of the memorylessness property.

Comment: Assuming $n>1$, it seems unlikely if you want the conditional distribution of $Y_{(2)}$ given $Y_{(1)}$ to be the same as the unconditional distribution of $Y_{(1)}$, even though $Y_{(2)} \ge Y_{(1)}$.  If $Y_{(1)}$ is not equal to the minimum of its support with probability $1$ then that is often not going to happen, and if it is then you have a constant distribution.

Comment: "...then the distribution of $Y_{(i)}|Y_{(1)}, ..., Y_{(i-1)}$ is identical." Identical to what? Note also that the conditional distribution of $Y_{(i)}$ given $Y_{(1)}, ..., Y_{(i-1)}$ would generally depend on $Y_{(1)}, ..., Y_{(i-1)}$, so it would change if the min/max of these is changed. (I don't know if $Y_{(1)}$ refers to the min or the max).

Comment: @Michael Identical means they have the same distribution. In the same way that the "identical" in IID means having the same distribution. $Y_{(1)}$ is the minimum.

Comment: That does not help. What is "they"? *What* has the same distribution as *what*? Perhaps you are asking if the conditional distribution of $Y_{(3)}$, given $Y_{(2)}=76, Y_{(1)}=21$, is the same as the conditional distribution of $Y_{(3)}$, given $Y_{(2)}=12, Y_{(1)}=11$? Or perhaps you are comparing it to the conditional distribution of $Y_{(2)}$ given $Y_{(1)}=8$? Or perhaps the conditional distribution of $Y_{(2)}$ given $Y_{(1)}=9$? Or perhaps all of these should be the same as the unconditional distribution of $Y_{(1)}$, so the specific values you condition on do not matter?

Comment: @Michael $Y_{(i)} | Y_{(1)}, ..., Y_{(i-1)}$ refers to the distribution of $Y_{(i)}$ given the **values** of $Y_{(1)}, ...., Y_{(i-1)}$. This is a well defined distribution. I would like the distributions $Y_{(1)}, Y_{(2)}|Y_{(1)}, ...$ to be identical. I'm genuinely confused what you're confused about? I'm not trying to be difficult.

Comment: Yes, and I gave you specific values such as 76 or 21. Suppose the distribution of $Y_{(1)}$ is uniform over $[0,1]$. What do you want the conditional distribution of $Y_{(2)}$, given $Y_{(1)}=y$ to be?  If it depends on $y$, then it cannot be the same as the distribution of $Y_{(1)}$ since that does not depend on any other parameter $y$. So the things you are requiring to be "identical" are not even of the same *type*--unless you actually want the conditional distributions to not depend at all on the things they are conditioned on. Which means you want $Y_{(2)}$ to be independent of $Y_{(1)}$.

Comment: Note also that there is no such thing as a random variable $Y_{(2)}|Y_{(1)}$. Or $X|Y$ for that matter. That shorthand is sometimes used to represent conditional distributions. So $P[Y_2\leq x|Y_1=y]$ is a function of $(x,y)$ while $P[Y_1\leq x]$ is a function of $x$ only, so it is not even the same type of thing.